# How do i hide a variable in Github

Tags: python, github, environment-variables, dotenv

i am trying to hide a password in my deployment on Github, but neither .gitignore with a config.py file nor dotenv works when i try to deploy. Anyone who knows a solution?

I connected my .gitignore to a config.py with my variable: APP_PASSWORD = "blablabla". However, it does not load when i run github through Heroku. Downloading dotenv and load_dotenv did not work either. It worked on my local environment, but not on github.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue; I had worked on a Discord bot, and I was trying to deploy it through Heroku. Instead of dotenv, I went on my Heroku dyno / project, and under settings, I created a config var, with the key being "TOKEN" and the value being my bot token. I was able to access this in my main.py by saying os.environ["TOKEN"] (after importing os and environ).